# AVIF header structure

Tags: avif

I'm interested in the following question: which .avi bytes are responsible for which fields (monochrome, width, height, etc.). On the Internet, I could not find the necessary information. Thank you in advance!

Some links I found on this question: https://github.com/AOMediaCodec/libavif/tree/905e30049fda48053fc2049bc08422cdb3292ac8

https://aomediacodec.github.io/av1-isobmff/

https://aomediacodec.github.io/av1-spec/av1-spec.pdf#page=41